# Angular component reference don't have all property

Tags: angular

I try to make a component that allows me to modify another component by passing a reference to it.
Here is what I try to do.

.html :

```
<my-component #myComponent></my-component>
<mk-on-boarding [connectedTo]="myComponent"></mk-on-boarding>
```

.ts :

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.connectedTo.getBoundingClientRect) {
        this.nativeElement = this.connectedTo;
    } else {
        this.nativeElement = this.connectedTo._elementRef.nativeElement;
    }
}
```

but I get this error : `Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined`. (cause getBoudingClientRect is undefined).
So I have three questions :
1) why getBoudingClientRect is undefined ?
2) why _elementRef is undefined ?
3) When I use `#myComponent` on a basic html like `<div>` all works perfectly ?

Really thanks if you can help me. I spend a lot of time on this problem without resolve it :s

**UPDATE**
Here a link to see what happened : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1q8zck (look errors in the console. There is no error when I try to get information from native html tag but when I try with a component I have an error)

Comment: Would you please share the entire code (or stackblitz) that is involved? For example, you are using `this.nativeElement` and `this.connectedTo` but we cannot see the code that defines these properties. Also: Which component do the html and ts files belong to?

Comment: I updated my post to add a stackblitz link.

Comment: @MaximilienFaure Where is the `getBoundingClientRect` function defined?

Comment: and what do you want to access by using `_elementRef.nativeElement;`? do you want to access all element or specific control?

Comment: I want to pass it to an other component (a angular material component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you place template varibale on component. It will implicitly refer component instance that's why you not able to get getBoundingClientRect() of component. If you want to get component elementRef, Inject ElementRef inside component, Then access it like this

**MyComponentComponent.ts**

```
export class MyComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public temp:ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**component.html**

```
<app-my-component #myComponent></app-my-component>
<app-on-boarding [connectedTo]="myComponent"></app-on-boarding>
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krqr2h)

Comment: So if I want to be able to do what I want, I have to modify the constructor of all the components that have to be connectedTo my component mk-on-boarding ?  I would like something more "dynamic" it's possible ?

Comment: Since both component are siblings of each other, I am not sure about  dyanmic approach

Comment: I use connectedTo from app-on-boarding to control app-my-component but app-my-component doesn't know anything about app-on-boarding. app-my-component does what it has to do, regardless of what app-on-boarding changes. That's why I wanted one to reference the other without the other having to do anything.

Comment: Then what about creating generic diretive which will provide elementRef of host directive?

Comment: it's the same thing for me. If I want to use my app-on-boarding component I must update the other component for include elementRef. So thanks for your answer I will update component's constructor for all my component who need app-on-boarding.

Answer (score 0):

The object that is referenced by the template variable `#myComponent` and then assigned to `@Input() connectedTo` is of type `MyComponentComponent`. This component class does not have a method `getBoundingClientRect` nor does it have a property `_elementRef`.